# How to change each uitableviewcell background color

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicolor

I want to change each cell background color in order.

This is my colors.And I just want to show them as shown in image.

I'm showing it with random colors now.But I want to show them in order.

```
var cellColors = ["F28044","F0A761","FEC362","F0BB4C","E3CB92","FEA375"]
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GroupTableViewCell
        let randomColor = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(self.cellColors.count)))
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: self.cellColors[randomColor])
    }
```

[image]

Comment: do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath. if you have some problems, show us code.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to delete this line

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! GroupTableViewCell
```

from your `willDisplayCell` function, because it already have your cell in parameters, and you just overriding it with new cell, and your new cell will be never used.

If you want to show colors in order, then you can use `indexPath`:

```
var cellColors = ["F28044","F0A761","FEC362","F0BB4C","E3CB92","FEA375"]
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: cellColors[indexPath.row % cellColors.count])
}
```

Comment: edited: Sorry I didn't see indexPath.row % cellColors.count thats worked.

Thanks

Comment: Also cell type shall be custom

Comment: @ShadowOf can we change the color of cell by using UITableViewRowAction ???  for example:                                                    let color = UITableViewRowAction(style: .normal, title: "Color") { (_, indexPath) in
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: cellColors[indexPath.row % cellColors.count])
}
           
        }

Comment: @ArgaPK you need additional work then. You should store somewhere knowledge that you changed color using this action, and reuse new color on dequeuing your cell.

Answer (score 3):

Make an array with the colors, maybe you have to create them dynammically but in this example they are hardcoded.

```
let bgColors = [UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.grayColor(), UIColor.whiteColor()];
```

Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath take the color at the correct index and set it for the cell. I don't know your actual setup but something similar to this should work.

```
let bgColor = bgColors[indexPath.row]
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = bgColor
```